# Digital Tries (JAVA) - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -13

Tags: java

So I was testing some codes from the Internet about Digital Tries for a project I have and I have stuck on this one because everything I try returns this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -13
```

This is where I found this code ([Code Source](http://www.programcreek.com/2014/05/leetcode-implement-trie-prefix-tree-java/))

TrieNode.java

```
class TrieNode {
    TrieNode[] arr;
    boolean isEnd;
    // Initialize your data structure here.
    public TrieNode() {
        this.arr = new TrieNode[26];
    }
 }
```

Trie.java

```
public class Trie {
    private TrieNode root;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Trie tr = new Trie();
    tr.insert("TEST");
    System.out.println("TEST " + tr.search("TEST"));
    }

    public Trie() {
        root = new TrieNode();
    }

    // Inserts a word into the trie.
    public void insert(String word) {
        TrieNode p = root;
        for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++){
            char c = word.charAt(i);
            int index = c-'a';
            if(p.arr[index]==null){
                TrieNode temp = new TrieNode();
                p.arr[index]=temp;
                p = temp;
            }else{
                p=p.arr[index];
            }
        }
        p.isEnd=true;
    }

    // Returns if the word is in the trie.
    public boolean search(String word) {
        TrieNode p = searchNode(word);
        if(p==null){
            return false;
        }else{
            if(p.isEnd)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // Returns if there is any word in the trie
    // that starts with the given prefix.
    public boolean startsWith(String prefix) {
        TrieNode p = searchNode(prefix);
        if(p==null){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    public TrieNode searchNode(String s){
        TrieNode p = root;
        for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
            char c= s.charAt(i);
            int index = c-'a';
            if(p.arr[index]!=null){
                p = p.arr[index];
            }else{
                return null;
            }
        }

        if(p==root)
            return null;

        return p;
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -13
    at Trie.insert(Trie.java:20)
    at Trie.main(Trie.java:6)
```

To Compile :

```
javac TrieNode.java Trie.java
java Trie
```

Any Ideas to solve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int index = c - 'a'` is working on the char `'T'` during the first iteration of your `for` loop.

In terms of `char` values, `'T' - 'a' = -13`, thus `index = -13` which throws the exception when checking the array.

**Edit:**

Your solution isn't working because you're using capital letters. In the article, the program uses only 'a' through 'z'. You can easily change your code to accommodate this:

```
char c = Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(i));
```

Comment: What could I use instead? int index = c - '0' ?

Comment: @rgettman He didn't ask for a solution. In fact, he didn't ask for ANYTHING!

Comment: My mistake. I DO NEED a solution. Tried int index = c - '0'  and int index = c - 'z' but the exception is still there

Answer (score -1):

please the foreloop in your insert should use lenght-1 instead

```
public TrieNode searchNode(String s){
        TrieNode p = root;
        for(int i=0; i<s.length()-1; i++){
            char c= s.charAt(i);
            int index = c-'a';
            if(p.arr[index]!=null){
                p = p.arr[index];
            }else{
                return null;
            }
        }

        if(p==root)
            return null;

        return p;
    }
```

Comment: Tried it, but I get the same thing again